# How do I list multiple married couples names on an inviation

Tags: abbreviations

I am listing multiple married couples as hosts for a wedding shower. Do I have to use Mr. & Mrs. before every name? The space on the invitation is limited.

Answer (score 3):

If you're mentioning their names to honour their contribution to the event, it would make sense to allow the proper space on the invitation to do so.

As a matter of English, the usual forms are

> Mr & Mrs Smith
>   Mr & Mrs John Smith
>   Mr John Smith & Mrs Jane Smith
>   John and Jane Smith
>   John and Jane

The plain "Smith" and the "Mr/s" form seem a little dismissive as an acknowledgement, although "The Smiths" might work. Depending on the length of the surnames, you might also find that using a form without the titles may not be any shorter.

You should also consider your group's norms for what is socially acceptable.