# Order of placing Mr. and Mrs. in a wedding card

Tags: phrases, american-english, politeness, salutations

I am designing a wedding card, I need to know how to start it, these are some samples:

1. Mrs. & Mr. Xyz invite you....
2. Mr. & Mrs. Xyz invite you....
3. Mrs. Abc & Mr. Xyz invite you....
4. Mr. Xyz & Mrs. Abc invite you....

Which is the best one to suit a wedding invitation? or suggest me some other lines which looks correct and polite in reading too.

**Note:** Couple inviting here are mom and dad of the bride.

Comment: Use Mr. Xyz and Mrs. Abc. Convention is to list male first then female, though there's no reason you can't do it the other way around if you'd prefer. You wouldn't do 1 or 2 because the couple isn't married yet.

Comment: Couple is married!

Comment: Ah, it sounded like you were designing a card for the wedding ceremony itself. In that case, I'd use Mr. and Mrs. Xyz unless they decided they would keep their surnames or hyphenate or double-barrel or something else.

Comment: No, actually the couple inviting here are mom and dad of the bride.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question of etiquette, not English.  Consult an etiquette book or site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wedding invitations in British English](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93358/wedding-invitations-in-british-english)

Comment: Also related: [How do I list multiple married couples names on an inviation](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/291402/how-do-i-list-multiple-married-couples-names-on-an-inviation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're *designing* a wedding card, you should put this way (if all parents are still alive) :

**Mr & Mrs Smith** for the parents of the *bride* &

the reverse for the young man.

However, if you design only one card for a reception, it's usualy the housewife who receives...

Answer (score 0):

I've almost always seen "Mr. and Mrs. Xyz and Abc", however, to be honest, I don't think anyone's going to call you out on switching it up (and if they do, it's kind of sexist of them).